# qme convert 1.7 GB raw file to 192 KB(!) vmdk

Tags: qemu, vmware, suse

I want to convert a raw file, wich was created with `dd` from the sda-data, to a `.vmdk` file to use it in ESXi. In short, I want to virtualize an old Suse 10.3 system as a VM.

On the Suse 10.3 system I have created the RAWFILE with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/opt/SuSE10_3.img
```

Then I converted this file to a vmdk file on a Suse 11.4 system using `qme`. (`qme` on 10.3 did not work)

```
qemu-img convert -f raw /media/RAWFILE -O vmdk /media/VMDKFILE.vmdk
```

Now this gives me only a very small file back, which is recognized by ESXi as a valid vmdk file, but which of course does not find any operating system at boot time due to its size.

Comment: Did you verify that the raw file (SuSE10_3.img) actually has the required data (`fdisk`, `kpartx` etc.)? I would copy the original disk (sda) from within a rescue system or something and not from a running system.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid raw-file. What do you mean with "copy the original disk (sda) from within a rescue system". Sorry, I'm still a total newbie.

Comment: Copying data from a disk that is currently in use is not a reliable way. One way is to boot that machine (the original disk is not virtual, correct?) into rescue mode (from CD/DVD) so /dev/sda is not in use. Then dd the disk to a different location. But if you're sure that the raw image is valid there's no need for that right now. What is `/media/RAWFILE`? Is it the img file mounted on a different host? You should clarify that in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. /media/RAWFILE is the raw-file I've created (dd ...) on the suse 10.3 system from the sda-file. The RAWFILE is now located on a 11.4 system in the media folder. I just copied it via MobaXterm from the Suse10.3 to Suse11.4.

Comment: I can not reproduce that, I just converted a raw image file to vmdk format without an issue. Do you see any errors or other messages since the conversion must be over pretty quick if it only results in a couple of KB. Does your filesystem have enough space where you try to convert that image?

Comment: "@No active partition@Disk read error@No operating system@Invalid CHS read@..."

So, there must be something went wrong with the dd action.

Comment: I agree, you probably should start over and consider the rescue system I mentioned in a previous comment. If you're not familiar with that you should probably ask someone who is.

Comment: I will try that and post the solution here. Thank you very much for your help!